# Matching rows with php array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table sessions with columns (`name`, `start`, `end`, `key` and `active`). Every 5 minutes I execute a PHP script running a commandline application which outputs an array.

```
array(
    [0]
        [name] => user1
        [key] => h2r92
        ....
        ....
    [1] ...
)
```

Now I would like to achieve

1) Match PHP array `name` and `key` with database. If the user and key exists do nothing (the session is alive). If an array item is not in the database, create a new row (new session)

2) For every session in the database that is not matched with the php array set end to current time and set active to 0 (session closed)

What is the best way to approach this?

Currently I have this code:

```
// get active sessions from db
    $db_sessions = array();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM lm_session WHERE feature_id = :fid AND active = 1";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array(':fid' => $fid));
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL))
    {
        $db_sessions[$row['key']] = $row['user'];
    }

    // loop through current sessions
    if(is_array($data['session'])){

        // New and existing sessions
        foreach($data['session'] as $session) {

            if(isset($db_sessions[$session['key']]) && $db_sessions[$session['key']] == $session['user']) {
                unset($db_sessions[$session['key']]);
            } else {

                // session does not exist
                $query = "INSERT INTO lm_session (`feature_id`, `user`, `workstation`, `in`, `key`, `active`) VALUES (:fid, :user, :system, :in, :key, :active)";
                $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
                $stmt->execute(array(':fid' => $fid, ':user' => $session['user'], ':system' => $session['system'], ':in' => $session['time'], 'key' => $session['key'], 'active' => 1));    
            }
        }
        // closed sessions
        foreach($db_sessions as $key => $user)  {

            $query = "UPDATE lm_session SET active = 0 WHERE feature_id = :fid AND user = :user AND `key` = :key AND active = 1";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute(array('fid' => $fid, ':user' => $user, ':key' => $key));
        }
    }
```

This works but not sure this is very efficient.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Lets write , what you already tried . By the way we can understand what is the problem exactly.

Comment: The best approach it to try something and then ask a question if some specific part of your code is giving you trouble.